# Как разобрать строку методом parse() класса SimpleDateFormat, чтобы получить разные форматы при чтении ячеек Excel c помощью библиотеки POI?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, poi

Пробую прочитать столбец в документе `Excel` и добавить прочитанное в список. Чтение формата даты пробую реализовать классом `SimpleDateFormat`, но требуется прочесть колонку с датой определенного формата и временем определенного формата, только не получается добиться данного результата, не понятно почему выкидывает

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dd.MM.yyyy"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at ru.app.doc.ReadExcelData.extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(ReadExcelData.java:73)
    at ru.app.doc.ReadExcelData.main(ReadExcelData.java:43)
```

Может кто нибудь подсказать в чем дело и как это реализовать?

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        String date = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        String time = "HH:mm";
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            // получение формата даты
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat(date);
            sdfDate.parse(date);
            columndata.add(sdfDate.format(cell.getDateCellValue()));
            // получение формата времени
            SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat(time, Locale.UK);
            sdfTime.parse(time);
            columndata.add(sdfTime.format(cell.getDateCellValue()));
        } else {
            columndata.add((int) cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
        }
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В метод `SingleDateFormat.parse` нужно передавать строку, представляющую дату, например 25.10.2020. Тогда он вернёт объект типа java.util.Date

Но, мне кажется, что Вам его вызывать вовсе не нужно. Ведь задача в том, чтобы получить строку из объекта типа Date. А она решается вызовом метода `SingleDateFormat.format`.

Просто удалите строчки с вызовом метода `SingleDateFormat.parse`

Если хочется формировать только время для ячеек, в которых нет даты, нужно понять, какую строку возвращает `sdfDate.format()` для таких ячеек. После этого сравнивать результат `sdfDate.format()` с этой строкой.

Comment: Наверное нужно условие поставить проверки получаемой строки, после этого выполнение, если удовлетворит условию

Comment: Выполнение чего?

Comment: Суть в том что без parse то работает), просто охото добиться того, что если в столбце дата, то выдаёт формат даты, если времени, то выдаёт только время, пока выдаёт и дату и время. Пока пользуюсь отдельным методом для выполнения чтения времени, а так если задать условие отдельно на дату и время в одном методе для чтения

Comment: Так анализируйте строку, которую возвращает `sfdDate.format()`